# What's the first anime to have different versions of theme songs by different MCs' voice actors?

Tags: anime-history, theme-song

Some anime have different versions of theme songs (OPs or EDs) by different MCs' voice actors. For example, *Blade Dance of the Elementalers* has different versions of EDs by each of its female MCs, [Est](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQ0sIvxSlO8), [Claire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57KlYoS0xMM), [Ellis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkLUuz0FaUg), [Fianna](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDrq_2IhCfw) and [Rinslet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMZTkoSBJBQ).

What's the first anime to have different versions of OPs or EDs by all of its **MCs**, **male MCs** or **female MCs**?

Comment: I don't know if it was the first, but probably the most famous is *Neon Genesis Evangelion*, where the ED (Frank Sinatra's "Fly Me to the Moon") is sung by a different character's VA in each episode.

Comment: "Fly Me to the Moon" is complicated - I'm pretty sure for the TV broadcast version the only VA who sang it was Megumi Hayashibara (Rei), with the other versions having vocals by Yoko Takahashi or other singers, or just being instrumental. The versions with the other VAs apparently only appeared on the DVD release. They did also record their own version(s?) of "Cruel Angel's Thesis".

Comment: @F1Krazy That can't be true, since the anime has 26 episodes, but only two female main heroines. Three if you count Katsuragi Misato. I only remember the voice of Hayashibara Megumi singing it for the anime, too.

Comment: @Ocean [It is](https://evangelion.fandom.com/wiki/Fly_Me_to_the_Moon). Each episode's version of the song has unique instrumentation, with Rei, Asuka, and Misato each singing multiple versions. I don't know whether there's a version out there that uses the same version for all 26.

Comment: @F1Krazy I meant that there aren't 26 characters so it is impossible to have the ED "sung by a different character's VA in each episode". Sooner or later the same seiyuu is going to appear again. Semantics.

Answer (score 2):

The first one that comes to mind is **Sakura Taisen: Gouka Kenran (1999)**.
You can listen to the different versions [here](https://openings.moe/list/?s=sakura%20taisen%20Gouka).

There might be earlier examples, though.